# Updating Data Behind a Projection?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have 2 entities, `Line` which has multiple `Tags` :

[image]

**In my UI I have a list box :**

[image]

**This listbox is bound to a projection :**

```
var tagNames = someline.Tags.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
var tagsList = from t in rs.Tags join n in tagNames on t.Name equals n into tags select new { Name = t.Name, IsTagged = tags.Any()};
dgvTags.DataSource = tagsList;
```

**Problem :**

I wish to check the checkbox and it automatically add the tag / or remove the unchecked tag from the Line.Tags collection. Is this possible in a simple way or do I have to catch the click and do the work and refresh the grid?

Problem 2... before I can do the above Ive noticed the checkbox does not even check, is there a reason for this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind data source to projection you are creating something like readonly (one-way) data binding - there are no entities on behind which could be updated. Moreover this is not a case for some automagic data binding. You are showing information about all tags and selecting which tags must be added to your line. That means that you must manually handle events fired by your UI, get Id of selected tag and use it to add real tag entity to your line.

Comment: As I thought, thankyou. Reason I asked was because Im a beginner in so much of the linq & EF functions so I didnt know if there was a better way.